# How to consistently display PDF in a webpage using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, pdf

I am having trouble getting JavaScript to consistently display PDFs in a webpage.
Some PDFs display without problem but some just bring up a white page with no error messages.

PDFs are uploaded by users using a C# WinForms application and are stored in a SQL server table using a VARBINARY(MAX) datatype. These PDFs are then made available to a webpage via an API call.
The code to read the PDF into a byte array is:

```
byte[] file;
using (var stream = new FileStream(DocumentTextBox.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            }
        }
```

The JavaScript code I have to call the API, convert the response into a base64, encoded URI and then write to a new webpage is:

```
const response = await postData(API_URL + 'GetDocument/', data);
const exam = await response.json();
                
let pdfWindow = window.open("")
pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:applicaton/pdf;base64, " + encodeURI(exam) + "'></iframe>")
```

For the API call, the data object contains the GUID of the PDF to be displayed.

Some of the main changes I have tried are:

- PDF.js - I want the files to be displayed as PDFs, not images, so that users can interact with them normally
- Replacing the iframe with embed - could only get it so that it would display a "Request URI too long" error
- Removing base64 from the src - this broke all PDFs

Because of the IT security setup, I am not allowed to store the PDFs in a fileshare so storing in a database and using an API is the option to make the PDFs available to the webpage.

Having spent over a week trying numerous changes, I would appreciate some advice about how to resolve this problem

Thanks

Comment: You will face the problem of having size constraints on your database at some point by storing them in there. Also, it *will* suffer performance degradation as more and more files get stored in. It's not a good practice. Reconsider doing storage in a server and storing only the reference path on the db. Also, if security is an issue you might encrypt the file on the fly and save it encrypted.

Comment: I would suggest that the users download the pdf, so they can interact with them using different programs. They can view the pdf in the browser as well. But to do that, to program viewing of the pdf and interaction with the pdf in browser is (*I would say) impossible. That is why browsers created their special view screens for pdf (open a pdf file with browser to have a look).

Comment: The LEADTOOLS JavaScript [Document Viewer](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document/document-viewer-html5) Library displays PDF in an interactive JS control. The toolkit is also capable of [loading base64](https://www.leadtools.com/support/forum/posts/t12748-) encoded data from a memory stream without needing to save the data locally. You can find the an online demo of the Document Viewer [here](https://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/DocumentViewer/). You can also download [a free evaluation](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads) of the toolkit. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor).